# Python - Move files from one folder to other with some exceptions

Tags: python

I would like to move files from one folder to other but with some file exceptions . One is some specific file names and other is with all folders starting with AEIOU.  How could I do this last exception? The specific file names already have it. Thanks.

```
import os
import shutil

source_dir = "c:/data/abc"
special_dir = "c:/data/zxy"

exclude_files =["file.docx", "file2.xls"]

allfiles = os.listdir(sourcedir)
for each_file in allfiles:
   if each_file not in exclude_files:
      full_path_source_file = os.path.join(source_dir, each_file)
      full_path_target_file = os.path.join(special_dir, each_file)
      shutil.move(full_path_source_file, full_path_target_file)
```

Comment: `os.path.isdir(each_file) and not each_file.startswith('AEIOU')`

Comment: This line should come before the if right? Thanks

Comment: @user128285 `isdir()` needs to be passed a full path (unless `source_dir` happens to be the current working directory).

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own Exception and throw it when necessary.
An example for your foldersstartinwith AEIOU:

```
class VocalFolder(Exception) :

    def __init__(self, path) :
        self.path = path

    def __str__(self) :
        return repr(self.path)
```

Assuming that `exclude_files` contains the names of the folders starting with AEIOU:

```
try:
    if each_file not in exclude_files:
        ## do your stuff here
    else:
        raise VocalFolder(each_file)
except VocalFolder as ex :
    print "Exception:", str(ex)
```

Hope this helps.

In the same way you can do it for the files.

Comment: It is just so hard not to think about Exceptions when reading exceptions... ;)

Comment: I'm not opposed at all to using exceptions for flow control where it makes sense, but here it simply doesn't help: The action OP wants to take for the excluded files is to *skip* them, which is already done with simply leaving out the `else:` clause. Raising an exception here doesn't accomplish anything. OPs problem seems to be with expressing the condition.

Comment: you are completely right, I just misunderstood his intentions: **with some exceptions**

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this:

```
import os
import shutil

source_dir = "c:/data/abc"
special_dir = "c:/data/zxy"

exclude_files =["file.docx", "file2.xls"]

allfiles = os.listdir(sourcedir)
for each_file in allfiles:
   if each_file not in exclude_files and
      not (os.path.isdir(each_file) and each_file[0] not in 'AEIOU'):
      full_path_source_file = os.path.join(source_dir, each_file)
      full_path_target_file = os.path.join(special_dir, each_file)
      shutil.move(full_path_source_file, full_path_target_file)
```

That will check with specific case, if you want to check if it's a vowel without care for case you would want to do `each_file[0].upper() not in 'AEIOU'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functions to help with your task:

- [`os.path.isdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir)
- [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)
- [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Your additional constraint for directories starting with `AEIOU` can then be expressed as `isdir(path) and name.startswith('AEIOU')`. Note though that you have to pass a **full path** to `isdir()`, but only check for the name with `startswith()`. You therefore need to build your full paths before your check, and separate just the name once again (using `basename()`).

But if you build all that into that single `if` statement, it becomes quite unreadable. I would therefore recommend factoring it out in a function:

```
def is_excluded(path):
    name = basename(path)
    if isfile(path) and name in ["file.docx", "file2.xls"]:
        return True
    if isdir(path) and name.startswith('AEIOU'):
        return True
    return False
```

The check in your `if` statement then simply becomes `if not is_excluded(path)`.

---

Everything together:

```
from os.path import basename
from os.path import isdir
from os.path import isfile
import os
import shutil


source_dir = "c:/data/abc"
special_dir = "c:/data/zxy"


def is_excluded(path):
    name = basename(path)
    if isfile(path) and name in ["file.docx", "file2.xls"]:
        return True
    if isdir(path) and name.startswith('AEIOU'):
        return True
    # Or, if you actually want to check for dirs starting with a vovel:
    # if isdir(path) and name[0] in 'AEIOU':
    #    return True
    return False


allfiles = os.listdir(source_dir)
for each_file in allfiles:
    full_path_source_file = os.path.join(source_dir, each_file)
    full_path_target_file = os.path.join(special_dir, each_file)
    if not is_excluded(full_path_source_file):
        shutil.move(full_path_source_file, full_path_target_file)
```

---

**Edit**: I just realized based on the comments that you might want to check for directories starting with **vowels**, so the individual characters `['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']`.

If that's the case, your new check would simply become `name[0].lower() in 'aeiou'` (case insensitive) or `name[0] in 'AEIOU'` (case sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

You also could try the following approach:

```
import os
import shutil

source_dir = "c:/data/abc"
special_dir = "c:/data/zxy"

exclude_files =["file.docx", "file2.xls"]
allfiles = os.listdir(sourcedir) # dirs are also included

for each_file in allfiles:
   full_path_source_file = os.path.join(source_dir, each_file)
   full_path_target_file = os.path.join(special_dir, each_file)

   if os.path.isfile(full_path_source_file):
      if each_file not in exclude_files:
         shutil.move(full_path_source_file, full_path_target_file)
   else: # each_file is a folder
      if not each_file.upper().startswith('AEIOU'):
         shutil.move(full_path_source_file, full_path_target_file)
```